# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'scatter'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter

I'm trying to make cluster of latitude and longitude.
the code gave an error in `plt.scatter(data['Lng'],data['Lat'])` line

the error is:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'scatter'
```

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
data = pd.read_csv("pk.csv") 
data.head()
lat_long = data.drop(['country', 'iso2','admin', 'capital','population', 
'population_proper'] , axis = 1)
lat_long.head()
plt.scatter(data['Lng'],data['Lat']) # error here
```

Comment: This is a standard Matplotlib question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `k-means`, or `artificial-intelligence` (!) - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `matplotlib`, which is surprisingly missing, despite the title).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It should be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 3):

Or it can be:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Also you can read [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more information and clearity.